# Wpf ResourceDictionary for Style and Brushes and how to MergedDictionaries

Tags: wpf, custom-controls, resourcedictionary, mergeddictionaries

I hope someone can clarify the situation I have below.

I have a simple CustomControl style based on a Button in a ResourceDictionary named SHButtonStyle.xaml

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:SHButton}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ResourceKey= Background}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:SHButton}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I also have a ResourceDictionary named Brushes as below:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Background" Color="Red"/>
```

I also have a Themes folder with Generic.xaml which has the MergedDictionaries as below:

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="/TestCustomControl;component/SHButtonStyle.xaml"/>
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

I have tried merging the ResourceDictionary for the Brushes within the Generic.xaml as I understood it is best to merge all ResourceDictionary's within Generic.xaml?

But the only way I can get this to work is with an additional MergedDictionaries for the Brushes within the SHButtonStyle.xaml. Is this correct or what am I missing when merging the ResourceDictionary's within the Generic.xaml.

Thank you in advance for your assistance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either merge the brushes resource dictionary in theme/generic.xaml directly, or merge them both at global level in `App.xaml`:

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApp1.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/TestCustomControl;component/Brushes.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/TestCustomControl;component/themes/generic.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

The `MergedDictionaries` of themes/generic.xaml usually contains "standalone" resource dictionaries for custom controls without any dependencies to resources in other resource dictionaries.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. If this was a control library with many controls, utilising a common set of colors it is my understanding that each control styles is be best placed in their own resource dictionary(RD) and the colors in a further RD? You would then merge these in generic.xaml? This dll would be ref by the application to access each of the controls?
I have tried merging the Brushes.xaml and the SHButtonStyle.xaml in the generic.xaml to no effect.
Although merging them both at the global level works this would appear to go against the principal of a self-contained control library?

Comment: The default styles for the controls in a "self-contained" control library should be defined in `themes/generic.xaml`. So far so good. Your "understanding that each control styles is be best placed in their own resource dictionary(RD) and the colors in a further RD" is not correct though. If a resource dictionary that you merge from `themes/generic.xaml`, or any other resource dictionary other than the global one in the `App.xaml` of the consuming app for that matter, references a resource that is defined in another resource dictionary, you should merge this one into the consuming RD.

Comment: Thank you for the Clarification, it is much appreciated.